# Android Studio Firebase Recycler Adapter using Java

Tags: java, android, firebaseui

[Firebase Recycler Adapter Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxmCW.png)

hi, so im trying out to create a crud app with firebase as my database. i encountered these errors:

There is no default constructor available in 'androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder'
Cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseRecyclerAdapter'
Cannot resolve symbol 'firebase'

i already linked my firebase using the tools in android studio and it says it was a success. i currently have no clue as to what i should do to overcome this error. i just started with android studio today to make my own project.

so i am expecting that the main adapter class will load and that the firebaserecyler adapter will connect. idk how it isn't connected when i simply followed through every step of the tutorial twice.

Comment: Since firebase import is not resolved, can you share your build.gradle file? You might be missing an import there.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information tomerpacific asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: please include some relevant code